# include php file and working with array

Tags: php

I am trying to include different files, each of which contains a navigation source code.

```
$db->query("SELECT MOD_ID FROM `ACCOUNTS_MODULE` WHERE ACCOUNT_ID='".$_SESSION['ACCOUNT_ID']."' and STATUS='1' and (END_TS<=0 or END_TS>'".date("U")."') ");
while($res = $db->data()){ $user_module_ids[]=$res; }

    foreach($user_module_ids as $key => $element)
{
if(file_exists($vz.'module/'.$element['MOD_ID'].'/lang/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.inc'))
    { 
      require_once($vz.'module/'.$element['MOD_ID'].'/lang/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.inc');       
    }
}
```

The content of the included files looks like this:

```
$modul['navigation'][]='<li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="'.$global['serverurl'].'module/1/code/url.php" class="nav-toggle nav-link">
                            <i class="icon-users"></i>
                            <span class="title">'.$lang['mod1'][0].'</span>
                            <span class="selected"></span>
                            <span class="arrow open"></span>
                        </a>                            
                  </li>';
```

After including all of the files, I want to have a complete navigation inside the `$modul['navigation']` as an array.

I include 5 file, normaly there should be 5 entries in the array!?

The result of `print_r($modul['navigation'])`, is always just the contents of the last-included file.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't it saving all parts in the `$modul['navigation']` array?

Comment: _What i do wrong_ I dont know, what is the problem??

Comment: Like i wrote, there are only the last part in the $navigation from the last include file. I include 5 file, normaly there should be 5 entries in the array!?

Comment: I dont see any way that you are including 5 files. If you show thefull code MAYBE we can help. Otherwise, we probably cannot. Of course we could take a few **guesses** but thats not productive

Comment: sorry, i've updated the first source code, you can see now where the datas come from and that the inlcude function is into a foreach-part. Hope anyone can say me what my mistake at this code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was outside this script. In another while-part, was a database-selection wich overwrite the $modul variable, so there was everytime only the last datas inside the array.

Sometimes it's easy when you're not blind ;-)